# Not able to connect to Mongo DB Atlas with Spring Boot App

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I am creating a spring boot application and trying to connect Mongo DB atlas and its giving me below exception :

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.read(SocketStream.java:112) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.4.jar:na]
```

Connection string in application.properties:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb+srv://<user>:<pass>@abc.mongodb.net/test?ssl=false&connectTimeoutMS=1000&socketTimeoutMS=1000
```

Comment: Are you able to connect with that url from mongo client?

Comment: @Santoshb : yes I am able to connect it from mongo client.

Comment: To be more specific did you use this connection string to connect

mongodb+srv://<user>:<pass>@abc.mongodb.net/test?ssl=false&connectTimeoutMS=1000&socketTimeoutMS=1000

or you gave each field seperately

Comment: MongoDB Atlas requires SSL.

Comment: @Santoshb I only used this uri connection string, no separate fields used.